# open mp taking longer for black_scholes algorithm in C

Tags: c, openmp, pragma

im having trouble with the parallelization of this black_scholes code fragment, i added a simple #pragma omp parallel for but it take 50 times more time 
im sure there is a problem with shared memory but i really don't know what

```
black_scholes_iterate (void* the_args)
{
  black_scholes_args_t* args = (black_scholes_args_t*) the_args;

/* Unpack the IN/OUT struct */

 /* IN (read-only) parameters */
 const int S = args->S;
const int E = args->E;
const int M = args->M;
const double r = args->r;
const double sigma = args->sigma;
const double T = args->T;

/* OUT (write-only) parameters */
double* trials = args->trials;
double mean = 0.0;

/* Temporary variables */
gaussrand_state_t gaussrand_state;
void* prng_stream = NULL; 
int k;

/* Spawn a random number generator */
prng_stream = spawn_prng_stream (0);

/* Initialize the Gaussian random number module for this thread */
init_gaussrand_state (&gaussrand_state);

/* Do the Black-Scholes iterations */
printf("here2: %d \n",M);


#pragma omp  parallel for
for (k = 0; k < M; k++)
  {
    const double gaussian_random_number = gaussrand1 (&uniform_random_double,
                        prng_stream,
                        &gaussrand_state);
    trials[k] = black_scholes_value (S, E, r, sigma, T, 
                   gaussian_random_number);

  /*
   * We scale each term of the sum in order to avoid overflow. 
   * This ensures that mean is never larger than the max
   * element of trials[0 .. M-1].
   */
  mean += trials[k] / (double) M;
}
```

after further testing i noticed that htis part of the for loop take a lot of time: 
const double gaussian_random_number = gaussrand1 
(&uniform_random_double,prng_stream, &gaussrand_state);

Comment: The variable `mean` is being modified each iteration of the loop.  I don't really have OpenMP experience, but that seems like something that wouldn't go well with parallelization.   **Edit:** also `parallel` is missing a letter in your code.  Is that just a copy error?

Comment: yes actually it just a copy error, thats what i was thinking of the error is for the mean part, but the for loop isnt using that variable just adding to it

Comment: Adding to the variable *is* using it.  Adding to a variable asynchronously leads to race conditions.  What happens if you calculate the mean outside of that OpenMP loop?  Alternatively, what if you took advantage of C11's Atomic types and operations for `mean`?

Comment: Can u give me an example of calc the mean outside the loop?

Comment: Just comment out the second to last line so you no longer calculate the mean in the loop and see if it makes a difference. It is trivial to calculate it either afterwards or by calculating it local to each OMP thread. But remove it first to see if it is the sticking point.

Comment: The PRNG `gaussrand1` probably relies on state variables and cannot be used easily with different threads. Generating PRNG is often slow and hard to do in parallel (also modern X86 processors have a single hardware RNG per processor but not per core). However, `black_scholes_value` is likely much slower than `gaussrand1`. So what you can do is generate the PRNG with one thread in chunks and then run `black_scholes_value` in parallel with the remaining threads. This is a bit tricky but I think an efficient solution can be done with OpenMP that's not too ugly.

Comment: Is this the code you are using https://github.com/changok/BlackScholesSequential/blob/master/black_scholes.c ?

Answer (score 0):

```
double *a;
a = malloc(M * sizeof (double));

for (int k = 0; k < M; k++)
{

  const double gaussian_random_number = gaussrand1 (&uniform_random_double,
                        prng_stream,
                        &gaussrand_state);
  a[k]=gaussian_random_number;

}
#pragma omp  parallel for 
   for (int k = 0; k < M; k++)
{

  trials[k] = black_scholes_value (S, E, r, sigma, T, 
                   a[k]);




  mean += trials[k] / (double) M;
}
```

@Z Boson's answer was the solution, i got a significant speed up and it helped a lot thank you soo much

Comment: `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+: mean)`